# Insert into table values from single variable SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way to capture the values to be inserted to a table into one variable as comma separated values and use the variable to execute `insert into` statement.  For example, create a test table as

```
create table id_test (id int, name varchar(10))
```

declare a variable and set the value for the variable to be the values to be inserted into table with comma separated as shown below:

```
declare @test as varchar(60) ;
set @test = '10,''john''';
```

Now use the variable `@test` in `insert into` as

```
insert into id_test (id,name) values(@test)
```

Reason for asking this question is that, I do not want to pass all the variables from web page to a stored procedure.  Instead I want to pass pass one variable from Web page which holds the comma separated values to be inserted into table.

Comment: The best method is to pass all variable's values as a separate parameter. Your method will lead to SQL Injection

Comment: @Madhivanan , is there any specific reason to do so?  I thought,  better to have one variable instead of passing individual variables as each table has more number of columns.

Comment: yes it leads to sql injection stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Comment: Thanks Madhivanan.. I checked the link you gave.  I will consider sql injects before finalizing solution! thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a dynamic query you can achieve this. In stored procedure after variable declaration

```
declare @test as varchar(60); 
set @test = '10,''john''';   

declare @sql AS VARCHAR(MAX) = 'insert into id_test (id, name) values('+@test+')'

--USE EXEC() to execute your insert command
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Looks wide open to SQL Injection attacks.